# Finding Text Within a GDB Log

Tags: linux, gdb

I logged some data from GDB to a file, gdb.txt, which looks like this:

```
    0x00fca0ab:    pop    ebp
    0x00fca0ac:    dec    edx
    0x00fca0ad:    xlat   BYTE PTR ds:[ebx]
    0x00fca0ae:    jmp    0xb31bbe76
    0x00fca0b3:    mov    bl,0x8a
    0x00fca0b5:    fmul   DWORD PTR [edi+0x21828f9b]
    0x00fca0bb:    mov    BYTE PTR [ebp+0x45],ah
    0x00fca0be:    adc    BYTE PTR ds:0x66e7d2ad,ch
    0x00fca0c4:    xchg   edx,eax
```

I want to search for specific ROP gadgets, so I would be looking for something like:

```
    [address]:    xchg   esi,eax
    [address]:    ret
```

How would I go about searching for such text? I would have to look in specific columns so what would be the best way to do so? BTW this is Ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
awk '{print $2}' gdb.txt #it prints the second column in the file
```

then you can look for needed data by using grep. In total:

```
awk '{print $2}' gdb.txt | grep data
```

Comment: that would only return what I searched for in the second column. I need it to return the memory address as well so I am looking for something like "search gdb.txt columns 2&3 for data"